# EF 5.0 - Loading collections of T

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to write the following code more abstract.

```
private void LoadRelatedData(TabAccount tabAccount)
{
    if (ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.Entry(tabAccount).Collection(x => x.TabAccountLangs).IsLoaded == false)
    {
        var list = (from x in ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.TabAccounts
            from y in x.TabAccountLangs
            select y).ToList();
    }
}
```

The parts I would like to abstract are the following:

1. **.Entry(tabAccount)** -> should take every EntitySet
2. **x => x.TabAccountLangs** -> should take the property I specify on calling the Method (maybe threw MemberExpression)
3. **from x ...TabAccounts** -> should load the DbSet from the EntitySet I am calling the method with
4. **from y in x.TabAccountLangs** -> should be the property from above

About the abstraction, I just want to avoid copy/pasting this code over and over and just changing the 4 mentioned points, would be happy to be able to call this method with paramaters given and the method does the rest.

So instead of:

```
private void LoadRelatedData(TabAccount tabAccount)
{
    if (ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.Entry(tabAccount).Collection(x => x.TabAccountLangs).IsLoaded == false)
    {
        var list = (from x in ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.TabAccounts
            from y in x.TabAccountLangs
            select y).ToList();
    }
}

private void LoadRelatedData(TabElement tabElement)
{
    if (ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.Entry(tabElement).Collection(x => x.TabElementLangs).IsLoaded == false)
    {
        var list = (from x in ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.TabElements
            from y in x.TabElementLangs
            select y).ToList();
    }
}
```

Something like this (only pseudo code):

```
private void LoadRelatedData(object obj, object collection, object dbSetOfObj)
{
    if (ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.Entry(obj).Collection(x => x.collection).IsLoaded == false)
    {
        var list = (from x in ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.dbSetOfObj
            from y in x.collection
            select y).ToList();
    }
}
```

And call this method:

```
LoadRelatedData(tabAccount, TabAccountLangs, TabAccounts);
LoadRelatedData(tabElement, TabElementLangs, TabElements);
```

Hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Data.Entity; // For the Include extension method.

private void LoadRelatedData<TEntity, TRelated>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TRelated>> navigationProperty)
    where TEntity : class
    where TRelated : class
{
    if (!ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.Entry(entity).Collection(navigationProperty).IsLoaded) 
    {
        var list = ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.Set<TEntity>().Include(navigationProperty).ToList();
    }
}
```

And then, you can call it by writing:

```
LoadRelatedData(tabAccount, ta => ta.TabAccountLangs);
LoadRelatedData(tabElement, te => te.TabElementLangs);
```

However, you know that such a call will load all of the related data, for any x? That is, you may load a considerable amount of data in a not particularly optimized way. If you only want to load the related data of a single entity, you can load the collection from the object returned by the `Collection` call:

```
private void LoadRelatedDataOfSingleObject<TEntity, TRelated>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TRelated>> navigationProperty)
    where TEntity : class
    where TRelated : class
{
    var collectionEntry = ConxCore.Instance.EntityModel.Entry(entity).Collection(navigationProperty);
    if (!collectionEntry.IsLoaded) collectionEntry.Load();
}
```

However, if you want to load the data for many objects, you should consider using one of the [`Include` extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly I cannot run the first method, getting the following compile error:
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

It wont let me specify .SelectMany<TEntity>. :(

Comment: Okay fixed the method by changing the code to this: ....SelectMany(navigationProperty.Compile()).ToList(); the .Compile() was missing, now its working fine.

Comment: Sadly this doesnt update the .IsLoaded property of the Entry, do you know a way to do so, without calling the load on every single entity and without include?

Comment: @RandRandom: Do not use `Compile()` in this case - you will potentially run a large number of queries. Instead, use the code from my last edit. Second, if you want `.IsLoaded` to be updated, I think calling `Select` instead of `SelectMany` would work.

Comment: Nope calling Select didnt change a thing, this code still runs everytime and the if (...IsLoaded) makes no difference, any aditional ideas?

Comment: Btw, your rewritten code doesnt really work, no compile error but the SQL Statement looks like this:
SELECT NULL AS "C1",
       NULL AS "C2",
       NULL AS "C3",
       NULL AS "C4"
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS X
        FROM   RDB$DATABASE) AS "B"
WHERE  CAST(1 AS SMALLINT) = CAST(0 AS SMALLINT)

Comment: @RandRandom: OK, I have dialed down the code - I am just using an `Include()` call, which should work and update the `IsLoaded` value. (Why did you specify "Without include" in your previous comment?)

Comment: The reason behind this all, is that I have extended the entity partial class with custom properties. And not all of them are in use threw out the application life, in all wpf windows. So I thought instead of writing GetAccountForWindowA methods (yeah not using MVVM buts thats another story) with includes for the properties that will be used, I wanted to place the load logic in the Get of each property - so when someone requests the property the associated data is being loaded, but doing it like you have done it now is perfect for me. Thx.